# Resize UITableViews programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have 3 tables, but sometimes I have to hide the 3 one. So:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    if (s == 2)
    {
        // Adjust frames
        self.tableA.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 500, 200);
        self.tableB.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 500, 200);
        [self.tableC setHidden:NO];

        self.tableC.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200 + 100 +40, 1024, 200);

    }
    else
    {

        self.tableA.frame = CGRectMake(0,    100, 500, 600);
        self.tableB.frame = CGRectMake(500, 100, 500,600);
        [self.tableA sizeToFit];
        [self.tableB sizeToFit];
        [self.tableC setHidden:YES];
}
```

The problem is that when `s!=2`, the tableA and tableB do not resize to take the full height I set. The have 200 as height ...
I created the tables with XIB.
I would like to resize tableA and tableB in such way they have 600 as height, but only when tableC is hidden.

Comment: please be clear about your requirement.

Comment: have you tried to use [self.tableA reload] after resizing?

Comment: Yes I did. reload just reload data..

Comment: Why do you call sizeToFit after setting the frames?

Comment: Just a try. Even without calling it, nothing change...

Answer (score 0):

Allowing `Autolayout` in the IB and deleting `sizeToFit` worked out.